# Zero amplitude and frequency from audiokit tracker on device but works on simulator

Tags: swift, audiokit

## AudioKit

I have two view controllers that are doing different audio related function. The first view viewController, needs to record audio and also do real-time processing of the amplitude and frequency of the sound being recorded. The second view controller needs to play the recorded audio, and do some stuff with the playhead.

My problem is that when I go back and forth a few times between the two screens on my iphone 6 device, the amplitude and frequency of the tracker only equal 0. This behavior does not happen on my simulator. Similarly, I've tried different combinations of starting + stopping the tracker and/or the audio engine at different points in the workflow but then I just get crashes along the lines of https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/issues/643. One thing I have been trying to figure out is how to make a singleton instance of the aukiokit so I can only start the engine once, but I can't get it from examples.

Here are the key sections of code that use the audiokit, microphone and tracker:

First view controller in the workflow

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func analyzeSpeechAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //Audiokit.stop()
        stopTimers()
        let vc = AnalysisViewController(nibName: "AnalysisViewController", bundle: nil)
        print("ANALYZING")
        do {
            try player.reloadFile()
        } catch { print("Errored reloading.") }
        
        let recordedDuration = player != nil ? player.audioFile.duration  : 0
        if recordedDuration > 0.0 {
            recorder.stop()
        }
        tracker.stop()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    func stopTimers(){
        if timerTest != nil {
            timerTest!.invalidate()
            timerTest = nil
        }
        if timer != nil {
            timer!.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }
    }
    var mic: AKMicrophone!
    var tracker: AKFrequencyTracker!
    var silence: AKBooster!
    var mainMixer: AKMixer!

    var timerTest : Timer?
    var micMixer: AKMixer!
    var recorder: AKNodeRecorder!
    var player: AKAudioPlayer!
    var tape: AKAudioFile!
    var micBooster: AKBooster!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         AKAudioFile.cleanTempDirectory()
        AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium
        do {
            try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
        } catch {
            AKLog("Could not set session category.")
        }
        AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
        AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
        mic = AKMicrophone()
        tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic)
        tracker.start()
        silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
        
        micMixer = AKMixer(mic)
        micBooster = AKBooster(micMixer)
        
        // Will set the level of microphone monitoring
        micBooster.gain = 0
        recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: micMixer)
        if let file = recorder.audioFile {
            player = try? AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
        }
        mainMixer = AKMixer(micBooster)
        do {
            try recorder.record()
        } catch { print("Errored recording.") }
        AudioKit.output = mainMixer
    }
    viewDidAppear(){
         AudioKit.stop()
         AudioKit.output = silence
         AudioKit.start()
         if timer == nil{
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target:self, 
            selector:  #selector(ViewController.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
    @objc func updateUI() {
        frame = frame + 1
        print("AMP")
        print(tracker.amplitude)
        print(tracker.frequency)
      }
}
```

Second View Controller

```
class AnalysisViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: LineChartView!

    @IBAction func recordSpeechNavigation(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
        //AudioKit.stop()
        player.stop()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func playButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        playAudio()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //move to completion handler
        
        player.completionHandler = {() -> Void in
            self.playerStatusButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
            self.timerTest!.invalidate()
            self.relativePlayheadPosition = 0.0
            self.movePlayhead()
            print("complete")
        }
    }
}
```

I kind of mashed up a bunch of examples to get this far so I apologize if I am improperly using some of the AudioKit methods. The key behavior occurs between viewDidLoad(), viewDidAppear() and updateUI() of the first view and recordSpeechNavigation() of the second view.

Does anyone have any insight into what might be happening or how I can properly implement this stuff?

Comment: Is there any way to encourage an answer to this? I've tried so many variations, including following the "Conductor" singleton pattern and even trying to handle pitch tracking in Beethoven. Every variation creates some error during different phases of the audio engine lifecycle. I understand that others have encountered such issues when performing multiple different actions with some ios audio components. Many of those threads have no conclusion. This is the only bug stopping me from publishing my app so an answer to this issue would be fully appreciated.

Comment: I was just facing this problem. I think the reason for this could somehow be your device set to silent... Try moving that switch to ringing, it worked then for me. I'll investigate that and give you an answer when I found something out

Comment: @Muli the device was not set to silent. I was able to hear playback before any crashes happened.